# Is asking for a specific group's strongest arguments for one of their beliefs opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

Successful previous questions:

- [According to Creationists, what are the strongest arguments against abiogenesis?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/92460/50422)
- [According to Catholicism and Eastern Orthodoxy, what are the strongest apologetic arguments for the divine inspiration of the deuterocanonical books?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/86011/50422)
- [According to Protestantism, what are the strongest apologetic arguments against the doctrine of Intercession of Saints?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84041/50422)
- [According to Latter-day Saints, what are the strongest apologetic arguments for the divine inspiration of the Book of Mormon?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/83901/50422)
- [What are the strongest apologetic arguments in defense of the veracity of the doctrine of Intercession of Saints?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84039/50422)
- [What are the strongest arguments for the divine inspiration of the Bible?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/83868/50422)

Current question in dispute: [According to non-inerrantist Christians, what are the strongest arguments against the inerrancy of the Protestant Bible?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/92924/50422)

Comment exchange under that question:

> **Luke Hill**: I don’t see how failure to close those previous questions changes anything I said. Do you not think the question is Opinion based?
>
> **Me**: I think it is as opinion-based as any of those other questions, so you would have to vote to close them all in order to remain consistent. I also think that determining whether a question is opinion-based is opinion-based. Feel free to continue this discussion on meta.

**Question**: Is asking for a specific group's strongest arguments for one of their beliefs opinion-based?

Comment: It is always going to be a matter of opinion which arguments are 'weaker' and 'stronger'. Many conclusions are based on multiple arguments which, taken as a whole, pose a compelling conclusion. The idea of 'weaker' and 'stronger' individual arguments being instrumental in the establishing of a verdict is erroneous, as any properly conducted forensic/judicial case will show. Juries are swayed by a _variety_ of cogent arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Subjective terms always leave open the possibility for the interjection of opinion and you certainly aren't going to ask for the lamest, least plausible arguments so you might as well leave off the word strongest and assume that those will be the ones lead with.